# How to loop inside array?

Tags: java, android

[ASK]
How to loop inside array? this is right?

```
weather_data = new Weather[]
{
for (i= 0; i < listOfMenu.size(); i++) {
new Weather(R.drawable.dring1, listOfMenu.get(0)),
}
};
```

Comment: Clearly that is not right.

Comment: try to create a List<Weather> first. On the loop, copy to list... corrects the listOfMenu.get to listOfMenu.get(i). After loop, converts your list in array using toArray() of List object.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Its not clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] elements = { "a", "a", "a", "a" };

for( int i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++)
{
String element = elements[i];
String nextElement = elements[i+1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, let me show you.

To enter inside a array and go around with this array you use a simple for, as you did:

```
for ( parameter : arrayName)
    instruction
```

If by example you want to print the values that are inside the array, you should do like this:

```
int[] arrayNum = {87, 68, 52, 5, 49, 83, 45, 12, 64};   /
for(int i : arrayNum) 
System.out.printf("Array Elements" + arrayNum[i]);
 }
```

I didn't quite understand what you are trying to do, but my answer was a direct response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't.

Long answer is that it isn't apart of the Java syntax.  You have the code to loop through it right there, all you have to do is move it outside.  Check out this handy snippet:

```
    Weather[] weather_data = new Weather[listOfMenu.size()];
    for (i= 0; i <= listOfMenu.size()-1; i++) {
        weather_data[i] = new Weather(R.drawable.dring1, listOfMenu.get(i));
    }
```